# How do I encrypt a password in Wordpress using Wordpress salt?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, passwords, salt

I want to encrypt the password being sent into the database, with the standard Wordpress salt, just like Wordpress does it when you create a new user. I know I can find my salt in the wp-config.php. So I don't need to generate the salt; I just need to encrypt the password.

So that when I create mypassword0, what is sent to the database is the string of text encrypted by my Wordpress salt.

Here is my original code that works. (thank you [Yadav Chetan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2257413/yadav-chetan) for your help!) Now I just need to add the salt encryption code.

```
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $query = "INSERT INTO mytable_one
          (user, pass)
          VALUES
          ('".$_POST['user']."', '".$_POST['pass']."')";

        $query = "INSERT INTO mytable_two
          (fname, lname)
          VALUES
          ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."')";

        mysql_query($query);

         }else{
    ?>
    <div class="content">
        <form method="post">
            <div><strong>First Name:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input id="first-name" name="fname" type="text" /></div>

            <div><strong>Last Name:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input id="last-name" name="lname" type="text" /></div>

            <div><strong>User:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input id="user-login" name="user" type="text" /></div>

            <div><strong>Password:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
            <div><input id="user-pass" name="pass" type="text" /></div>

            <div><input id="submit-button" value="submit" type="submit" />
        </div>          
        </form>
    <?php }?>
```

---

**UPDATED:**

[RRikesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370034/rrikesh) suggested I change the mysql_* to WPDB code. So I tried to change it over to wpdb, and also I need to integrate it in with the other code. So can you help me fix this updated code?

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $firstname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lname'];
    $username = $_POST['user'];
    $password = $_POST['pass'];

    $wpdb->query( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
           "INSERT INTO  mytable_one
          (user, pass) VALUES (%s, %s)",
             $username,
             wp_hash_password($password)
      )
    );
    $wpdb->query( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "INSERT INTO  mytable_two
            (fname, lname) VALUES (%s, %s)",
               $firstname,
               $lastname,
        )
    );

    }else{
?>
<div class="content">
    <form method="post">
                <div><strong>First Name:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
                <div><input id="first-name" name="fname" type="text" /></div>

                <div><strong>Last Name:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
                <div><input id="last-name" name="lname" type="text" /></div>

                <div><strong>Username:</strong><span class="errortext">*</span></div>
                <div><input id="user-login" name="user" type="text" /></div>

                <div>Password:</div>
                <div><input id="user-pass" name="pass" type="text" /></div>

        <div><input id="submit-button" value="submit" name="submit" type="submit" /></div>          
    </form>
<?php }?>
```

---

---

**UPDATE2**

I was unable to get the WPDB method to work. however, using my otd method I was able to has the password. Here is the working code:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $password = $_POST['user_pass'];
            $hash = wp_hash_password('$password');

            $query = "INSERT INTO wp_users
              (fname, lname, user, pass) VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$_POST['user']."', '".$hash."')";

            mysql_query($query);

        }else{
    ?>
```

Perhaps I should open a new question about the WPDB because this question was about hashing the password, which is solved.

Comment: First, don't use `$_POST` in your queries, or the `mysql_*` functions. Use MySQLi or PDO instead. Second, you will have to generate salt, as it is different per user. Also, you want to store the salt together with the user.

Comment: well it is working for me but if you have a better method feel free to visit that question and give a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010409/how-do-i-create-a-php-form-for-creating-new-row-and-inserting-data-into-it As far as the salt, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Of course it works, it is just very unsafe. Google for "SQL injection" and you'll know more. As far as the salt, have you tried anything?

Comment: thank you for the input; I would like to hear your alternative method

Comment: And by the way, the POST is only on admin page where only 2 or 3 registered administrative users will have access to it. visitors to the page will ever see or have access to this code. Still unsafe?

Comment: As far as the Salt, I want to use pre-existing Wordpress salt so that these users I create can be authorized as registered users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`wp_hash_password()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password) to hash your password.

[**Don't use `mysql_*` functions as they were deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and were removed in PHP 7.0.0.**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Use the [WPDB Class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instead.

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        INSERT INTO  mytable_one
        ( fname, lname, user, pass )
        VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s )
        ",
           $firstname,
           $lastname,
           $username,
           wp_hash_password( $password )
        )
);
```

Comment: how can i do several fields like this and also include the password?

Comment: I tried to do it and modified my original working code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010409/how-do-i-create-a-php-form-for-creating-new-row-and-inserting-data-into-it, and added the code i tried, at the end of the question. Can you help fix it?

Comment: wow that looks so much simpler... let me try it... only thing is how about for two separate databases? and i fixed my thing i tried above...

Comment: i updated my try in the question again based on your new code, trying to put them in separate databases

Comment: also should it actually be `$fname, $lname, $user, wp_hash_password($pass)`? or is there a reason you wrote different names?

Comment: or perhaps I should wrap `$wpdb->query( );` around the second set also? or maybe change the first one to `$wpdb->query1( )` and the second wrap `$wpdb->query2( )` around it?

Comment: No, use your actual variables for instead of `$firstname`, `$lastname`, etc. I used explicit names so that you can understand. The `( fname, lname, user, pass )` are your column names. Each `%s` is a placeholder for the variables `$firstname`, `$lastname`, etc.

Comment: by variables, you mean like `name="firstname"`?

Comment: I mean things like `$_POST['fname']`, `$_post['lname']` and other POST variables you got from your form. I just tried the code, it works.

Comment: your code did not work. No data was submitted to the database. what could be wrong?

Comment: oh, I think I understand now. I think you didn't understand that it **must** come from the form. It cannot be explicit. The data is entered into the form and then submitted. The on SUBMIT, it runs this SQL query.

Comment: So I tried several things to try to call the data from POST but it didn't work.

Comment: what if I did something like `$firstname = .$_POST['lname'].,
    $lastname = .$_POST['fname'].,
    $username = .$_POST['user'].,
    $password = .$_POST['pass'].`?

Comment: `$firstname = $_POST['lname'];  $lastname = $_POST['fname'];` No `.`

Comment: still did not work. Nothing was inserted into database when submitted.

Comment: I updated the question update with the new code, but the form still does not work. nothing is added to the database.

Comment: `$wpdb->query1` is totally wrong. It should be `$wpdb->query` like in the example above.

Comment: yea actually that's what I am using. I fixed the question. Still doesn't work.

Comment: No it isn't what you're using. You're using `$wpdb->query1` and `$wpdb->query2`. Replace both with `$wpdb->query`.

Comment: well I'm stuck here; but while I wait for an answer on this, should it be instead add another variable of `$hash = wp_hash_password( $password )` and then replace where $password is currently, with `$hash`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28247/discussion-between-user2281674-and-rrikesh)

Comment: ok I am stuck. I guess I just have to use my previous method because this one is not working.

Comment: yeah well i used my other method and used did the password hash method here, so that was helpful. if you can tell me how to fix your method I will be happy to use it. however until then I don't have any more time to waste. I read the whole page for WPDB but to no avail.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer and instead open a new question about WPDB, since this question was about Wordpress password hashing and it is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

you should use bcrypt for securing passwords

here is an example class that use for my projects.

```
<?php

    // How to use it

    // $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(15);
    // $hash = $bcrypt->hash('password');
    // $isGood = $bcrypt->verify('password', $hash);

    class Bcrypt {
      private $rounds;
      public function __construct($rounds = 12) {
        if(CRYPT_BLOWFISH != 1) {
          throw new Exception("bcrypt not supported in this installation. See http://php.net/crypt");
        }

        $this->rounds = $rounds;
      }

      public function hash($input) {
        $hash = crypt($input, $this->getSalt());

        if(strlen($hash) > 13)
          return $hash;

        return false;
      }

      public function verify($input, $existingHash) {
        $hash = crypt($input, $existingHash);

        return $hash === $existingHash;
      }

      private function getSalt() {
        $salt = sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $this->rounds);

        $bytes = $this->getRandomBytes(16);

        $salt .= $this->encodeBytes($bytes);

        return $salt;
      }

      private $randomState;
      private function getRandomBytes($count) {
        $bytes = '';

        if(function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes') &&
            (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) !== 'WIN')) { // OpenSSL slow on Win
          $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($count);
        }

        if($bytes === '' && is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
           ($hRand = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) !== FALSE) {
          $bytes = fread($hRand, $count);
          fclose($hRand);
        }

        if(strlen($bytes) < $count) {
          $bytes = '';

          if($this->randomState === null) {
            $this->randomState = microtime();
            if(function_exists('getmypid')) {
              $this->randomState .= getmypid();
            }
          }

          for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
            $this->randomState = md5(microtime() . $this->randomState);

            if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
              $bytes .= md5($this->randomState, true);
            } else {
              $bytes .= pack('H*', md5($this->randomState));
            }
          }

          $bytes = substr($bytes, 0, $count);
        }

        return $bytes;
      }

      private function encodeBytes($input) {
        // The following is code from the PHP Password Hashing Framework
        $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
          $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
          $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
          $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
          if ($i >= 16) {
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            break;
          }

          $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
          $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
          $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
          $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

          $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
          $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
          $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
          $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
        } while (1);

        return $output;
      }
    }



    ?>
```

Comment: Can you use this to log into Wordpress? If I created a user with this, would Wordpress validate this as a valid user? That's what I want to do.

Comment: I did not understand you need for wordpress but this is a good information for who wants to secure their passwords.